# Suppose the name of a column in a dataframe is unknown to me, how can I sort the df according to the values in that column?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to sort a dataframe in descending order according to the values in a specific column whose name is supposed to be unknown to me (i.e. I know it but I am not allowed to use it). The only clue is that it is the last column of this dataframe.

I've tried `arange()` and `order()` but they doesn't work. I also noticed that if I try to use `names(df)[ncol(df)]`, I will get the name of that column as a character. However, the correct argument formating in `arrange()` seems to be `columnName in two grave accents` rather than `"columnName"`. So I don't know how to correctly passs the name I got to the functions I want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R

```
mtcars[order(mtcars[tail(names(mtcars), 1)]), ]  #ascending
mtcars[order(mtcars[tail(names(mtcars), 1)], decreasing = TRUE), ] #descending
```

tidyverse

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% arrange_at(vars(last(names(.))))  #ascending
mtcars %>% arrange_at(vars(last(names(.))), desc)  #descending
```